# Binding HTML content to a "RichHTMLTextBlock" in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am having a WPF application, in which i am using RichTextBox and binding it to a field in the database which contains the data as a HTML text. Also i applied ***TextFormatter="{StaticResource HtmlFormatter}"*** for the RichTextBox.  Now if in the field i have a paragraph with some html styles applies like font color, font size etc they are supposed to appear in the same style.But i am not able to see the font size in the application, though font style and font color are applied.

Can anybody help on this ?

Thanks in advance!!!